# Symfony 2.3 How to include Expression Language

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, rule-engine

I am wondering if there is a way to include the Expression Language Component available on 2.4 version into 2.3? Or is there another rules engine available for Symfony 2? Please let me know if there is a way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.4 is not out yet, so you can't at the moment, but later, it will be also a package as any other symfony bundle, but I would strongly suggest, that you upgrade you symfony project to 2.4 . It's scheduled to come out today.

Comment: Yes I am waiting for a stable build, since its the first time that the expression-language is introduced. Agreed that the best solution is to wait for the inclusive bundle.

Comment: 2.4 is out since yesterday and it looks like, you don't need to change anything from 2.3 , just the composer to use 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply add symfony/expression-language to your composer requirements as there are no specific requirements for this component

https://github.com/symfony/expression-language/blob/master/composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3"
},
```

Comment: see this is the problem, I cannot update to 5.3.3 since the servers im using are not upgraded. Till I can update the servers to 5.3.3, i will have to find another way.